# lubuntu installation - I need gparted 1st

Tags: lubuntu

I was wondering if the lubuntu live CD contains gparted too? I'd like to instal lubuntu on my friend's laptop, but I need to create partitions 1st.
By the way, what format should I give to the future partitions? Ext4, just like in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installer uses ext4 by default too. The installer can also do partitioning.

Comment: I hear you. So, you are saying that I should just let the installer handle the partitioning, correct?

Comment: You can do that or use do it manually, it's offered during install.

Answer (score 0):

In the Lubuntu Installer, as well as all Ubuntu installers, you will find that you can easily resize your hard drive partitions. When it does this you will chose to keep windows and Lubuntu by selecting "install them side by side" and then easily choose how much room each operating system will have.